# Automapper - flattening of object property

Tags: automapper

let's say I have

```
public class EFObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NavId { get; set; }
    public NavObject Nav { get; set; }
}

public class DTOObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NavId { get; set; }
    public string NavName { get; set; }
}
```

My expectation was high, and I thought to my self the built-in flattening should handle this, so my mapping is very simple

```
CreateMap<DTOObject, EFObject>().ReverseMap();
```

Unfortunately, converting `DTOObject` to `EFObject` does not work as expected because `EFObject.Nav` is null. Since I used the name **NavId** and **NavName** I would expect it to create a new **NavObject** and set the `Nav.Id` and `Nav.Name` accordingly.

***My Problem* :** Is there a feature in Automapper that will allow me to achieve the intended result without having to manually write a rule to create an NavObject when mapping the Nav property?.

Answer (score 0):

> Unflattening is only configured for `ReverseMap`. If you want unflattening, you must configure `Entity` -> `Dto` then call `ReverseMap` to create an unflattening type map configuration from the `Dto` -> `Entity`.

as noted by `Automapper` documentation [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html)

Comment: If I switch the mapping `CreateMap<EFObject, DTOObject>().ReverseMap()`, Nav is not null but `Nav.Id` is 0, even if `NavId` is non-zero.